# Crontab doesn't run node script on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run node script as CRON job on Ubuntu 14.04 server. I am using `nvm`.

I have tried:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env node /var/www/apps/gmail-api/exe/m.js recent x@x.x
```

as well as:

```
* * * * * node /var/www/apps/gmail-api/exe/m.js recent x@x.x
```

and finally:

```
* * * * * ~/.nvm/bin/node-v6.6.0-linux-x64 /var/www/apps/gmail-api/exe/m.js recent x@x.x
```

neither worked.

However if I run:

```
node /var/www/apps/gmail-api/exe/m.js recent x@x.x
```

it works fine.

Why doesn't crontab run my script?

Comment: Make sure that your crontab is working. Do you have the end of line at the end of the cron? 

http://serverfault.com/questions/230370/why-is-only-one-wget-command-working-in-my-crontab

Comment: Did you try the full, resolved version of the node executable path in the third example instead of making it relative with `~`? cron won't run as your user, so `~/.nvm` wouldn't exist anyway.

Comment: cron will not have a problem running as your user, but the typical case is to run cron jobs as root. in any case, most environment variables including $HOME are not available, therefore expansion of the `~` character won't work.

Comment: @Klodoma I added new empty line at the end of crontab file.
@mscdex I changed line into `* * * * * /root/.nvm/bin/node-v6.6.0-linux-x64 node /var/www/apps/gmail-api/exe/m.js recent x@x.x
` and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround:

I created script which I run inside `pm2` or `forever` npm module.

```
setInterval(()=>{
  child_process.exec('node scriptname.js arg1 arg2', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });
}, 60000)
```